# Redundant conformance of 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' to protocol 'decodable'/'encodable'

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, swift-protocols

I'm writing on an interally used framework making use of CoreLocation. Don't ask me why but I have the requirement to make `CLLocation` codable. So I came up with a struct

```
struct CLLocationEncodingStruct: Codable {
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let altitude: CLLocationDistance
    let horizontalAccuracy: CLLocationAccuracy
    let verticalAccuracy: CLLocationAccuracy
    let speed: CLLocationSpeed
    let course: CLLocationDirection
    let timestamp: Date

    public init(with location: CLLocation) {
        coordinate = location.coordinate
        altitude = location.altitude
        horizontalAccuracy = location.horizontalAccuracy
        verticalAccuracy = location.verticalAccuracy
        speed = location.speed
        course = location.course
        timestamp = location.timestamp
    }

    var location: CLLocation {
        return CLLocation(coordinate: coordinate, altitude: altitude, horizontalAccuracy: horizontalAccuracy, verticalAccuracy: verticalAccuracy, course: course, speed: speed, timestamp: timestamp)
    }
}
```

Then I'm conforming to `Codable` in an extension to `CLLocation`. Putting data into that struct or pulling the data out of it. To make this work, I also had to make `CLLocationCoordinate2D` conform to `Codable`. I did this by writing the following very sophisticated extension

```
extenstion CLLocationCoordinate2D: Codable {}
```

Now I wanted to do things right for a change, so I wanted to get started writing unit tests. The problem is that my extension to `CLLocationCoordinate2D` needs to be part of both targets: the unit test and the framework itself. Unfortunately this does not compile. It fails with

```
Redundant conformance of 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' to protocol 'Encodable'
```

Redundant conformance of 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' to protocol 'Decodable'

Pointing out that `CLLocationCoordinate2D` already conforms to the protocol at the same code line. Building the target that depends on said frameworks works perfectly though. Do you have any ideas to fix that?

Best,

geru

Comment: The error message states that there is another conformance to `Codable` somewhere else. Search with ⇧⌘F

Comment: I did. There is no other conformance. If you check the Issue Navigator, it will even have a grey area beneath the error
 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' declares conformance to protocol 'Decodable' here: 
that points directly to this one location. I suspect that this error happens because the file is part of both targets, the framework and the test target

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your extension should not need to be part of the tests target.

You import your main application target into the unit test with the `@testable` attribute

```
import XCTest

@testable import MyProject

class MyProjectViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {}
```

This allows you to use the classes, extensions etc from your project without adding them to the test target.

Comment: So to clarify: Protocols that I want to conform to with any mock objects need to be part of the target, but everything else shoud simply be imported?

Comment: yeah, only add things to the test target that are used for testing, like mocks and stuff. Import the thing you want to actually test